# Unable to boot Ubuntu after complete installation 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04

I successfully installed Ubuntu 16.04 from my USB disk after when I restart (as it suggest to restart) my machine it only shows the message:

`No Caching mode page found`

`Assuming drive cache: write through`

It keeps on showing these message until I force a shutdown. When I reboot again, it shortly pop up with this message:

`error:file '/boot/' not found.`

and continue to start my previous installed OS(Windows).
and again if I tries to reinstall Ubuntu it says there exist already a Ubuntu OS.
what should I do now ? Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.